# Large performance difference between comparing a variable to a fixed value and reading or writing from mapped memory address

Tags: c++, performance, benchmarking

I'm developing a software that runs on a DE10 board, in an ARM Cortex-A9 processor.

This software has to access physical memory addresses in order to communicate with the FPGA in the DE10, and this is done mapping /dev/mem, this method is described [here](https://bakhi.github.io/devmem/).

I have a situation where I have to select which of 4 addresses to send some values, and this could be done in 1 of 2 ways:

1. Using an if statement and checking a integer variable (which is always 0 or 1 at that part of the loop) and only write if it's 1.
2. Multiply the values that should be sent by the aforementioned variable and write on all addresses without any conditional, because writing zero doesn't have any effect on my system.

I was curious about which would be faster, so I tried this:

First, I made this loop:

```
int test=0;

for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++)
{
    if(test==9)
    {
        test=15;
    }
    test++;
    if(test==9)
    {
        test=0;
    } 
}
```

The first if statement should never be satisfied, so its only contribution to the time taken in the loop is from its comparison itself.

The increment and the second if statement are just things I added in an attempt to prevent the compiler from just "optimizing out" the first if statement.

This loop is ran once without being benchmarked (just in case there's any frequency scaling ramp, although I'm pretty sure it has none) and then its ran once again being benchmarked, and it takes around 18350 μs to complete.

Without the first if statement, it takes around 17260 μs

Now, If I change that first if statement by a line that sets the value of a memory-mapped address to the value of the integer test, like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++)
{
    *(uint8_t*)address=test;
    test++;
    if(test==9)
    {
        test=0;
    } 
}
```

This loops takes around 253600 μs to complete, almost 14 x slower.

Reading that address instead of writing on it barely changes anything.

Is this what it really is, or is there some kind of compiler optimization possibly frustrating my benchmarking?

Should I expect this difference in performance (and thus favoring the comparison method) in the actual software?

Comment: Are you compiling with optimization enabled? Benchmark results are meaningless without that

Comment: In the code as posted, the compiler has to allow for `address` pointing to `test`

Comment: @M.M What you mean exactly? 'address' is a void type pointer which is being casted to uint8_t* type pointer and then dereferenced, I'm writing the value of 'test' to that memory address (which is in the area mapped to /dev/mem).

Comment: @M.M And by the way, using optimization or not (up to -O3) didn't really change the difference.

Only the first loop (the one with comparisons) got meaningfully faster, it got almost 40% faster, but the second loop (the one accessing memory) changed almost nothing.

Comment: @M.M One point that maybe relevant to mention here, is that I used the option O_SYNC in mmap to open /dev/mem. 

And I've seen people saying this makes memory access to that area very slow, cause it forces these accesses to be non-cached (which is necessary here, once they must always be read by the FPGA).

Comment: The first loop could and should be optimized to nothing, so your report of it appearing to take some time is suspicious.  The second loop can't so easily be optimized because it is possible that `*(uint8_t*)address=test;` modifies `test`. (The optimizer doesn't realize that you have set `address` to point to some other location guaranteed to be distinct from `test` -- or from `address` for that matter)

Comment: [compare assembly between the two functions](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/G4vvcGcva)

Comment: How to benchmark is a bit beyond the scope of a single SO answer

Comment: @M.M Well, the optimizer usually can't be used for this software, to begin with. Remember I'm using this code to communicate with an FPGA through shared physical memory, which is why the O_SYNC option is used in mmap. Every single change to the value of any address in there has to be reflected in the physical memory right away, cache can't be used. And the compiler can't make any improper assumptions about the pointer either. So far It has always been compiled without optimization and it works exactly as it should, all changes are reflected exactly in the physical memory, as  seen by the FPGA.

Comment: @M.M Also, remember the compiler I'm using is very specific, the entire OS running on the DE10 board is compiled for that. The compiler in use here is `arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++`.

Comment: @M.M By the way, I just confirmed optimization cannot be enabled for this application. If I compile the codes with optimization on they all fail, because the optimizer doesn't know I need every single pointer operation to happen exactly as written and in the exact order as written. It also doesn't know that caching is disabled for that memory area.

Comment: The question really comes down to the idiosyncracies of the compiler you are using, then